# Configure codeigniter to only run under my domain

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter, dns

I have a certain ip address on a linux server and a domain pointing to the ip.
I set up a codeigniter app and after a while i realized that there are at least a couple of domains (not mine) also pointing to my ip address.
I need to stop the codeigniter serving the pages when the domain is not the one I own.
Is there a clean solution to this? Maybe something with the url-library? I wonder if there is a best practice in this case. But maybe the best practice would require to stop the other domain at some other point? SOmething like in apache config or htaccess?

Answer (score 1):

The good practice to achieve that is to use virtual hosts. You better read a guide about that before to do anything I'll say if you never worked with apache vhosts before.

By the way, what you should do in order to proper discriminate domains pointing to your server is the next:

Let's say your domain is www.mydomain.com and your site is located in /var/www/vhosts/myproject/

First, go to your apache2.conf file and add the line:

```
Include sites-enabled/
```

You should enable virtual hosts on your apache configuration and then create an www.mydomain.com config file under /etc/apache2/sites-available. It should be something like this:

```
# Ensure that Apache listens on port 80
Listen 80

# Listen for virtual host requests on all IP addresses
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/myproject
ServerName www.mydomain.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Then run:

```
a2ensite www.mydomain.com
```

Which will create a symlink in sites-enabled to that config file.

and then restart the service.

Hint: I dont know about codeigniter specific behaviour. When declaring the DocumentRoot in your www.mydomain.com file, you must point to the directory with the index.php file of your project. I:E. in FuelPHP is the public/ directory, so, in case you were working with Fuel, yo should write:

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/myproject/public/
```

So check specifically that you're pointing to the codeigniter front controller.

Repeat this for every other domain pointing to your server, whith specifical config files under sites-available.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Pointing many domains at one IP is a common situation. You just need to make sure that your apache configuration has VirtualHost set up to handle your domain and no one else's.

If you are worried someone on your host is setting their apache configuration up to point to your CI directory, you can try doing something like this in your index.php file:

```
<?php

if ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] != 'YOUR DOMAIN')
{
   // redirect, die, etc
}
```

As an aside (Edit):

Browsers send a "Host:" header when they make their request. This means that it will go to an IP address, but the server there reads the "Host" header and sends it to the correct virtual host (in apache, this would be based on ServerName). So, it probably is possible someone who shares a host with you can set up their apache config to point to your CI installation, but that's probably the only scenario where it would be a problem. Move to your own host you don't share with anyone and that scenario is removed as well.